# How to save hindi,marathi text in file and read it

Tags: android

I need to save the information that is coming from server in hindi/marathi (Either one of them). I need to save that information in my app's file and again need to read that information from the app as required. Right now I am getting that information but while reading it shows `???`. Please help me for the same.Also I need to show data in hindi in edittext,textview,input from user and on dialogs in either Hindi/Marathi. Please guide me for the same.
Thank You in advance :)

Comment: post the code for saving the file you have so far

Comment: Most probably you will need to deal with encodings. Make sure you retrieve, save, and read the data in the proper encoding. I don't know the corresponding encoding for hindi set, but it should be found on the internet.

Comment: Did you found any solution ? Please post, if found

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `OutputStreamWriter` which allow us to set character encoding.

```
String txt="मुझे जानकारी हिंदी / मराठी को बचाने की जरूरत है.";

OutputStreamWriter writer=new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),"UTF-8");
writer.write(txt);
writer.close();
```

Comment: FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile,"UTF-8");
Its not working :(